# Open Cart Module

Tags: email, opencart, payment-gateway, checkout

Need help.. My query is as follows

I have my e-commerce website up and running with all the products. People are visiting my website and they are unable to complete the checkout process because there is no payment gateway setup yet , due to some delay in the bank process the gateway is still not setup.

I did try the cash on delivery process but it resulted in a huge loss to me.
I wanted to know if it is possible to send an email confirmation to the customer with the order details, price and my bank details to which they can deposit the amount during checkout process in opencart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Bank Transfer" details for that, but it's essentially the same as what you've got with COD. The easiest thing to do is just set up another payment gateway such as paypal etc. There are hundreds of them available (other than the ones that come as standard).

Comment: **Bank transfer** and **CoD** are completely different if handled correctly - because with **Bank Transfer** the goods should not be shipped before they are paid (that means the money for respective order has already been received on the bank account of the seller). This creates no money loss since the shipping is already paid and if the customer wishes to return the goods he is bearing the return shipping costs. The only problem where CoD creates the loss is when shipped (for your money expecting to be paid later) but nobody picks up the package - you suffer from shipping costs here.

Comment: Don't use CoD or charge double shipping, if this payment method selected. Actually, the description of your issue is pretty vague. Jay answered you correctly, but looks like you don't satisfied. So what's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps for you and got an idea.

For my experience, depositing the money to the bank by the customer is a indeed huge waste of time. They shop online for the convenience of not going out or what.

For your question:

Try to search **cybersource** as they are our payment gateway and they are really secure.
I suggest, since you don't yet the payment gateway, upon checkout, inform the customer what will be the mode of payment that they are using - like **Credit Cart**, **Cash-On-Delivery** or thru **PayPal**.

I think there is still no module that requires your need but you should work now on getting the payment gateway done as it will really help you save time and money.

Once you complete your payment gateway, try to establish Shipping method: **Pick up from the store**, **Free Shipping *when within your country*** and thru Shipping Delivery Service like **DHL, FedEx, AmEx, etc**.

Good Luck.